# Try to install lib32-ncurses-compat-libs 6.04 on Antegros

Tags: arch-linux, ncurses, antergos, pgp

When I try to install lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs under Antegros (Arch derivate) I get an error message while checking the PGP signatures.
(The error message is in german, but it states, that the PGP signatures could not be checked).

```
lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs 6.0-4  (2016-07-07 23:34)
(Nicht unterstütztes Paket: Potenziell gefährlich!)
==> PKGBUILD bearbeiten? [J/n] („A“ zum Abbrechen)
==> ----------------------------------------------
==> J

==> Von lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs benötigt:
 - lib32-glibc (bereits installiert)
 - lib32-ncurses (bereits installiert)
 - gcc-multilib (bereits installiert) [makedepend]


==> Mit dem Erstellen von lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs fortfahren?[J/n]
==> -----------------------------------------------------------------
==> J

==> Erstelle und installiere Paket
==> Erstelle Paket: lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs 6.0-4 (Fr 6. Jan 15:37:42 CET 2017)
==> Prüfe Laufzeit-Abhängigkeiten...
==> Prüfe Buildtime-Abhängigkeiten...
==> Empfange Quellen...
  -> Lade ncurses-6.0.tar.gz herunter...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3058k  100 3058k    0     0   380k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  438k
  -> Lade ncurses-6.0.tar.gz.asc herunter...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   267  100   267    0     0    219      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   219
==> Überprüfe source Dateien mit md5sums...
    ncurses-6.0.tar.gz ... Durchgelaufen
    ncurses-6.0.tar.gz.asc ... Übersprungen
==> Überprüfe Signaturen der Quell-Dateien mit gpg...
    ncurses-6.0.tar.gz ... FEHLGESCHLAGEN
==> FEHLER: Eine oder mehrere PGP-Signaturen konnten nicht überprüft werden!
==> FEHLER:Makepkg konnte lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs nicht erstellen.
```

The documentation states on multiple pages that I have to install a pgp key, but I already did that, and receiving the key changes nothing.

```
[user@terminal34340 repos]$ gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys C52048C0C0748FEE227D47A2702353E0F7E48EDB
gpg: Schlüssel 702353E0F7E48EDB: "Thomas Dickey <dickey@invisible-island.net>" nicht geändert
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 1
gpg:                             unverändert: 1
```

The message is again on german, but it just states, that this did not change the key, and nothing has changed.

Do you guys have a clue what I am missing? In the help forums a lot of people had success with just installing the key.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Manually verify the files with `gpg --verify ncurses-6.0.tar.gz.asc`.

Answer (score 0):

I am the OP, but somehow this question does not show up under the "my questions" tab.

@Wieland comment was very good, when I tried to verify the file ( which I downloaded from [The FTP server mentioned in the PKGBUILD](ftp://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) ).

And I manually verified the file I got the follwing error.

```
[user@terminal34340 libncurses]$ gpg --verify ncurses-6.0.tar.gz.asc
gpg: die unterzeichneten Daten sind wohl in 'ncurses-6.0.tar.gz'
gpg: Signatur vom So 09 Aug 2015 02:35:21 CEST
gpg:                mittels DSA-Schlüssel 702353E0F7E48EDB
gpg: lookup_hashtable failed: Unbekannter Systemfehler
gpg: trustdb: searching trust record failed: Unbekannter Systemfehler
gpg: Fehler: Die Vertrauensdatenbank ist fehlerhaft
gpg: Sie können versuchen die Vertrauensdatenbank durch folgende Befehle
wiederherzustellen:
gpg:   cd ~/.gnupg
gpg:   gpg --export-ownertrust > otrust.tmp
gpg:   rm trustdb.gpg
gpg:   gpg --import-ownertrust < otrust.tmp
gpg: Falls dies nicht funktioniert, sehen Sie bitte im Handbuch nach
```

Sorry for the error messages being in german. But it basically states that trust database has errors and I should repair it. with the commands showed beneath. I did exactly that (So I did not delete the trustdb, i just moved it somewhere else) . After that I re-imported the keys, and still I am getting the same messages, but it works now.

```
[user@terminal34340 libncurses]$ gpg --verify ncurses-6.0.tar.gz.asc
gpg: die unterzeichneten Daten sind wohl in 'ncurses-6.0.tar.gz'
gpg: Signatur vom So 09 Aug 2015 02:35:21 CEST
gpg:                mittels DSA-Schlüssel 702353E0F7E48EDB
gpg: Korrekte Signatur von "Thomas Dickey <dickey@invisible-island.net>" [unbekannt]
gpg: WARNUNG: Dieser Schlüssel trägt keine vertrauenswürdige Signatur!
gpg:          Es gibt keinen Hinweis, daß die Signatur wirklich dem vorgeblichen Besitzer gehört.
Haupt-Fingerabdruck  = C520 48C0 C074 8FEE 227D  47A2 7023 53E0 F7E4 8EDB
[user@terminal34340 libncurses]$ gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 702353E0F7E48EDB
gpg: Schlüssel 702353E0F7E48EDB: "Thomas Dickey <dickey@invisible-island.net>" nicht geändert
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 1
gpg:                             unverändert: 1
[user@terminal34340 libncurses]$ gpg --verify ncurses-6.0.tar.gz.asc
gpg: die unterzeichneten Daten sind wohl in 'ncurses-6.0.tar.gz'
gpg: Signatur vom So 09 Aug 2015 02:35:21 CEST
gpg:                mittels DSA-Schlüssel 702353E0F7E48EDB
gpg: Korrekte Signatur von "Thomas Dickey <dickey@invisible-island.net>" [unbekannt]
gpg: WARNUNG: Dieser Schlüssel trägt keine vertrauenswürdige Signatur!
gpg:          Es gibt keinen Hinweis, daß die Signatur wirklich dem vorgeblichen Besitzer gehört.
Haupt-Fingerabdruck  = C520 48C0 C074 8FEE 227D  47A2 7023 53E0 F7E4 8EDB
```

I really don't know what happened, or what was the problem.